How to locate the path of an application that is automatically opening on a Mac in order to block it
I don't open the Acrobat Updater, but it keeps opening by itself periodically. My machine is working fine, so I don't want any updates and I'm annoyed by the constant notification window.

I couldn't find the location of the app that opens it. I attempted to use the Activity Monitor and found its location by clicking on CPU\Process Name\Open File and Port \Sample


The path shown is:

/Users/USER/Library/Application Support/Adobe/*/Adobe Acrobat
Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Acrobat Updater

I can't find it in Finder. There appear to be two names that I can't see:

Do you know how to find and obtain the actual path of this file so that I can add it to the Quitter app in order to automatically close it whenever it opens?

You see /Users/USER maybe because MacOS changed it considering it as sensitive information. try this command:
find "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Adobe" -name "Acrobat Updater"

Acrobat Updater might be put in Settings -> General -> Login Items & Extensions, you can disable it if you don't need it.
Login Items & Extensions might be in Settings -> Privacy & Security.

You are correct, I can use that command to locate the app. However, they appear greyed out, and in the Quitter app, I can find them, but when I add them, nothing shows up. I share the screenshots here https://ibb.co/qFCKmT6 and
https://ibb.co/9srzLJC

Sorry, I found out why I cannot add the Quitter app. I should add the app, not the content.

But the Quitter app does not close after the set time, so it's unclear whether it's still active in the background, which may cause the Quitter app to think it's still being used.

Are you using MacOS/Sonoma ?

Yes, I am using MacOS Sonoma, and in the setting I cannot find Update to disable it


Open the Terminal app (cmd + shift, type "terminal")
Use the find command with sudo (mostly to hide warnings), i.e.

sudo find "~/Library/Application Support" -name "Acrobat Updater"

It will ask for your system password. You should see the full path printed.

I tried but this does not return any result.

Hmmm, you could try just searching at / instead, but I wonder if you have a permissions issue, regardless of path you search in. Are you the root user?

Ah I see you needed to search in ~/Library not just /Library based on the other answer
